# mnps function of R twang package shows warning errors for Absolute Standardized Difference plot

Tags: r, plot, weighting, propensity-score-matching

I have a dataset with 3465 observation and 5 variables as follows (named: dataset)

#### Variables

$ Treat --> factor(3 level: "1", "2", "3") 
$ Age --> integer(eg. 24,54,etc.) 
$ Mortality --> integer(0=no,1= yes) 
$ LDL --> integer(eg. 200,120,143, etc.) 
$ Smoking --> integer(0=no, 1= yes)

I used mnps function in twang package  to weight my observations according to treat

#### mnps code

```
mnps.dataset <- mnps(treat ~ Age + LDL + Smoking, data = dataset, estimand = "ATE", stop.method = c("es.mean", "ks.mean"), n.trees=3000)
```

```
### Plot ###

Then I used plot function to assess the balance of the data after weighting.
There was no problem for plots 1 and 2, (balanced of treatment per iterations, and propensity score distribution of treatments.)

#### Plot code

```
plot(mnps.dataset, plots = 1) 
plot(mnps.dataset, plots = 2)
```

But when i wanted to run plot 3 for Absolute Standardized difference, it made an error with some warnings and an empty plot:

#### Warning Error

`plot(mnps.dataset, plots = 3)`

Warning messages:

```
1: In order(as.numeric(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In split(as.numeric(x) [ord], gg[ord]) : NAs introduced by coercion 
3: ...(same as error 1) 
4: ... (same as error 2)
5: ... (same as error 1) 
6: ... (same as error 2)
7: ... (same as error 1)
8: ... (same as error 2)
9: In panel.superpose(x, y, type = type, groups = groups, ... : NAs introduced by coercion 
10: ... 
11: ... 
12: ...
```

___________________ 

Note : "..." means repeated previous error

[Image of empty plot generated by mnps plot=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdzE3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `twang` (I was able to replicate it on my own dataset). There isn't anything you can do about it.

You can instead use the [`cobalt`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=cobalt) package, which facilitates balance checking and is compatible with objects from `twang`. A plot that conveys the same information as the type 3 plot is a Love plot, which can be called using `love.plot()` in `cobalt`.

If you run `love.plot(mnps.dataset, which.treat = .all)` you can see standardized mean differences for all pairwise comparisons. See the section in the `cobalt` vignette on [multi-category treatments](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/vignettes/cobalt.html#using-cobalt-with-multi-category-treatments) for more information on how to use it.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to know that it's a bug in twang package. I had used "your" excellent cobalt package instead after and it worked very well on my dataset. Many thanks.

Comment: I also wanted to know that is it possible to perform PS matching for studies with multiple treatments (like my dataset) in Cobalt or other R packages ,  something like binomial PS matching with nearest neighbor method as we do in MatchIt package,  Which produce matched dataset instead of weighting for analysis.

Comment: Glad you found `cobalt` helpful. I don't know of a good package for multi-category treatment matching. It's something I hope to add to `MatchIt` in the future.